# Unable to run django application on nginx web server?

Tags: django, nginx, webserver, web-deployment

I am new to django , i am facing difficulties in deployment of django project on Nginx web server
i have followed configuration steps from this article[how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04)

As nginx is successfully installed and working fine, but my application is not runnig?
Do i need to configure in my django project ?

please check this image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y64Sc.png)

Comment: The image you provide shows that your nginx installation is working fine. This has nothing to do with the Django or uWSGI. The tutorial you're following has additional steps. Have you completed them?

Comment: i have followed above tutorial completely till end

Comment: And what happens when you visit `http://server_domain_or_IP:8080` ? The image you provide, show up? If yes, then please share your nginx configuration and your uwsgi conf too. Also, have you restarted both nginx and uwsgi?

Comment: root@ubuntu-512mb-blr1-01:/etc/uwsgi/sites# cat curanest.ini
[uwsgi]

project = curanest

base = /home/curaapp


chdir = %(base)/%(project)
home = %(base)/Env/%(project)
module = %(project).wsgi:application


master = true
processes = 5

socket = %(base)/%(project)/%(project).sock
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true

Comment: i tried but ,its not aligning properly

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and edit appropriately, please!